# Ordering a leaderboard in repl.it

Tags: python, leaderboard, replit

Need to order a leaderboard that I have created in a program in repl.it.

When ordering, it currently seems to order each entry based on its first digit, so all single digit entries are ordered correctly, but all double digit numbers are sorted by the first digit only, so for example it orders 11 below 2 as it reads it as 1.

Any ideas?

NB. leaderboard stores names and scores and scores are definitely stored as a string so I need to change that to integers from your advice so far. Thank you. Have tried to change in second line down - file.write(str(score)) - but tells me must be a string not int. help? Code for this section below.

```
file = open ("Leaderboard.txt", "a")
file.write(str(score))
file.write(",")
file.write(nickname)
file.write("\n")
file.close()

Leaderboard1 = list()
Leaderboard_unsorted = "Leaderboard.txt"
with open (Leaderboard_unsorted) as fin:
  for line in fin:
    if line[0] != "0":
      Leaderboard1.append(line.strip())
Leaderboard1.sort(reverse = True)
```

Comment: convert the values to integer before sorting...

Comment: Sounds like your leader board is using strings for the values your trying to sort. a string sort on the strings `["3", "25","111"]` would output `111,25,3` since 1 is before 2 and 2 before 3 etc. If you want to sort them numerically you need them to be ints not strings. of course showing your code would make this much easier to tell you for sure rather than us just guessing

Comment: We're lacking both crucial and basic information, and I'm sure that repl.it has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Have included code in question now. Any help on how to change scores as strings to integers would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since  you didnt show any code I have to make an educated guess that your storing your values you want to sort as strings instead of ints. As such when sorting strings they are sorted char by char. If you want them sorted as numerical values either store them as ints insated of strings or at lest tell your sort function to consider them as ints.

```py
scores = ["23", "3", "111"]
print("string sort", sorted(scores))
print("int sort", sorted(scores, key=int))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
string sort ['111', '23', '3']
int sort ['3', '23', '111']
```

But for future, please share your code or at least a minimal example that reproduces your problem

Comment: Thanks for your help. Have edited with relevant code in question now. Just need to work out how to convert to integers within this code

Comment: Either change `Leaderboard1.append(line.strip())` to `Leaderboard1.append(int(line.strip()))` to save them as ints. Or you can keep them as strings but tell sort you want them sorted as ints by changing `Leaderboard1.sort(reverse = True)` to `Leaderboard1.sort(reverse = True, key=int)`